# I am unable to close octave

Tags: shutdown, paths, etc, octave

I had a problem with installing Octave. Now I am unable to close it once it is opened. And I am unable to shutdown the computer. What path should I set, what `/etc/environment` should I set?

I had used these commands to install:

```
$ sudo apt-add-repository ppa:octave/stable
$ sudo apt-get update
$ sudo apt-get install octave
$ octave
```

[image]

Answer (score 2):

You got this error message:

```
E: The repository 'http://ppa.launchpad.net/octave/stable/ubuntu bionic Release' does not have a Release file.
```

ppa:octave/stable does not support Ubuntu 18.04, so remove it from sources.list and install the octave package from the default Ubuntu 18.04 repositories instead. Open the terminal and type:

```
pkill octave  
sudo add-apt-repository --remove ppa:octave/stable
sudo add-apt-repository --remove ppa:mc3man/trusty-media
sudo apt-get update
sudo apt purge octave 
sudo apt install octave
```

Comment: I am getting error code one

Comment: I am unable to update apps , what to do?

Comment: The PPAs that were added to your sources.list are not compatible with 18.04, so you are unable to update any apps that were installed from these PPAs.

Comment: @karel anyway `apt-add-repository` and `add-apt-repository` [are synonyms](https://packages.ubuntu.com/bionic/all/software-properties-common/filelist).

Comment: @raghuram If this answered your question please click the checkmark to the left of this answer to mark it as accepted. The checkmark will change color from gray to green when it is clicked.