# i want to use ppsspp emulator on ubuntu. but i couldnt install due to some errors

Tags: apt, software-installation, ppa

This is what I see:

[image: screenshot of my terminal]

Maybe I should add some files to some directory. I'm extremely new to ubuntu so please give a detailed solution.

Comment: @karel how this Q&A differs from yours https://askubuntu.com/a/1260500/66509 ? It seems that you use the gold power in wrong manner. Being potential newbie OP may not have enough expertise to analyze and implement solution from "duplicate"...

Comment: @N0rbert I actually reviewed this question twice.The first time reviewing it from the review queue I caught it. The second time I didn't, so I voted to reopen it.

Answer (score 0):

Here you have two problems with repositories - they do not have packages for Ubuntu 20.04 LTS.

So you need to remove these repositories at first with

```
sudo add-apt-repository -r ppa:danielrichter2007/grub-customizer
sudo add-apt-repository -r ppa:ppsspp/stable
```

and then add [repository](https://launchpad.net/%7Esamoilov-lex/+archive/ubuntu/retrogames?field.series_filter=focal) which provides *ppsspp* package:

```
sudo add-apt-repository ppa:samoilov-lex/retrogames
sudo apt-get update
sudo apt-get install ppsspp
```